# Static React App/Webpage Multi-language

Tags: reactjs, react-intl, gatsby

I have spend a week to figure out this question currently I'm using gatsby to generate my static web app.
i have tried to do it

```
-pages 
--en 
---index.js 
---main.md 
---contact.md 
--zh 
---index.js 
---main.md 
---contact.md
```

it's kind a works, but still not exactly perfect solution.
i'm thinking about impelent React-Intl but i'm not sure. is it possible for static app/webpage?

any other suggestion ?

Comment: It seems like this would work just fine? What problems are you facing? Most multi-language sites I've seen namespace the different language pages like you're doing e.g. `/en/main/` & `/zh/main/`

Comment: Also react-intl will work just fine w/ Gatsby. Gatsby treats React the same as any normal React/Webpack project so if it works elsewhere, it'll work in Gatsby.

Answer (score 2):

we use [Instant](https://instant.cm/en/landing/react) as a multi-language solution for React. We have a static generated React app that we deploy to S3 and serve through CloudFront. In you React router you can make sure all paths are caught like `/en/some-page` and `/fr/some-page`. Then, based on this route you set the correct Locale in Instant and the tool will serve the correct language to the visitors.

Comment: in this way, you have generate to many files. after while it's get mess. to many file is hard to control. i find react-intl does better job. 
you can have n json file for n language and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

My current approach is using `react-intl` and `Gatsby-plugin-i18n` together. so I keeping the content of the pages in `Gatsby-plugin-i18n` and for everything else in react-intl. which is works totally fine so far.